# Edit password protected macro in Workbook 1 with another macro in Workbook 2

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I am trying to unprotect a project to delete a macro. I have 131 such files where this macro needs to be removed.
My issue is that I am not able to unprotect the project. I get Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method on the line "wb.VBProject.Unprotect password". I hope someone can assist me, please. It will be much appreciated!

```
Sub RemoveMacroInWorkbooks()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim vbComp As VBComponent
    Dim password As String

    ' Set the folder path where your workbooks are located
    folderPath = "C:\Users\DELL\Dropbox\Commodities"

    ' Set the password for the protected modules
    password = "password"

    ' Loop through each workbook in the folder
    fileName = Dir(folderPath & "\*.xlsm")
    Do While fileName <> ""
        ' Open the workbook with password
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & fileName, , , , password)

        ' Unprotect the VBA project if it is protected
        If wb.VBProject.Protection <> 0 Then ' 0 means no protection
            ' Provide the password to unprotect the VBA project
            wb.VBProject.Unprotect password
        End If

        ' Access the VBComponents of the workbook
        For Each vbComp In wb.VBProject.VBComponents
            ' Check if the VBComponent is a module
            If vbComp.Type = vbext_ct_StdModule Then
                ' Access the code module of the module
                With vbComp.codeModule
                    ' Find and delete the specified macro code
                    Dim startLine As Long
                    Dim endLine As Long
                    Dim i As Long

                    ' Find the starting line of the specified macro
                    startLine = 1
                    Do While startLine > 0
                        startLine = .Find("Sub navDashb", startLine, 1, -1, -1, False)
                        If startLine > 0 Then
                            ' Find the ending line of the specified macro
                            endLine = .Find("End Sub", startLine, 1, -1, -1, False)
                            If endLine > 0 Then
                                ' Delete the lines containing the specified macro
                                For i = endLine To startLine Step -1
                                    .DeleteLines i, 1
                                Next i
                            End If
                        End If
                    Loop
                End With
            End If
        Next vbComp

        ' Protect the VBA project again
        wb.VBProject.Protect password

        ' Save and close the workbook
        wb.Save
        wb.Close

        ' Get the next workbook in the folder
        fileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```